# How to make variable options

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I am new to jsgrid and I need some help please.

I saw that we can have many options while creating a JsGrid such as

```
{
    fields: [],
    data: [],

    autoload: false,
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
etc...
}
```

What I wish is to make a variable containing my options and send it to the Jsgrid as a one line , not one by one , I will give you an example to understand what I mean...I would like to do something like that :

```
var options ="width:1000, height:1000"; //add all needed options here
```

then create the jsgrid like this way 1:

```
var $grid = $("#gridcontent-" + name).jsGrid({fields: flds, data: data,options});
```

instead of doing it that way 2 :

```
var $grid = $("#gridcontent-" + name).jsGrid({fields: flds, data: data,width: "1000", height: "1000"});
```

the way 2 works, but I want to do something like what i named way1, because when we have many options it's easiar to see.

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why is it easier to see? You're mixing two data types there, and any function is just going to convert the string into an object anyway. How is `'width:100,height:100` any more readable than `{width:100,height:100`?

Comment: this answer is not helpfull, why some people here, instead of providing help ask such questions ? what do you get from trying to confuse a beginner ? anyway thanks. To answer your question, i am not saying that "width:1000, height:1000" is more readable than {width:100,height:100}, I am saying that 

var $grid = $("#gridcontent-" + name).jsGrid({fields: flds, data: data,options});

is more readable than var $grid = $("#gridcontent-" + name).jsGrid({fields: flds, data: data,width: "1000", height: "1000"}); 

especially when you add more options than width and height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.assign` or spread syntax:

```
var options = { width: 1000, height: 1000 };
// Using Object.assign:
var $grid = $("#gridcontent-" + name).jsGrid(Object.assign({ fields: flds, data: data }, options));
// Using spread syntax:
var $grid = $("#gridcontent-" + name).jsGrid({ fields: flds, data: data, ...options});
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, both syntax works well...I couldn't have find the solution by my own because I don't know any of these syntax, I am really thankfull....Please can you explain to me the difference? and if I use any of them is there any side effect on the property of my jsgrid or I can continue using it normally after that ? sorry if i am asking basic questions but I ma a beginning in JS

Comment: The difference is browser support: [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is supported by older browsers compared to [...options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: So it's better to use object.assign so that you guarantee that if the user has an older browser it will still works right ? and can you tell me what does exactly do these ... and the object assign ? just to understand thanks again

Comment: Please follow the links in my last comment to see browser support, and an explanation of what both techniques do (MDN is a great source of info: easy to google 'mdn Object.assign' etc to find good information on most JavaScript, HTML and CSS topics.)

Answer (score -1):

var options ="width:1000, height:1000";
var $grid = $("#gridcontent-" + name).jsGrid({fields: flds, data: data,options});

this is not possible with jsgrid, we have to define the jsgrid attributes one by one , and what you are trying to achieve is more or less same, So not a good idea to waste time on that, i suggest go with the normal behavior of jsgrid.